# How to fix PageMenu on ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu). I need fix menu with constraints by height. How to do this?
I know how to fix height of menu, no need answers about this. This problems with constraints AutoLayout. I need fix PageMenu on my ViewController.  And app must work on different devices.
 I try change Y value. but not work how I need.

```
pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by fixing my top view height equals 250, and fix all elements by constraints.

And when I write  this code bottom view fixed how I need.

```
pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 250.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
```

Comment: hiii @Zhanserik i have issue using CAPSPageMenu 
suppose i have a pagemenu tab with two view controllers.... in one of the view controller their is a button so when i click to that button i m navigating to child view controller but child view taking more time to load could u help me

Comment: @DilipTiwari Hello. Please share you code on Gist in the GitHub